# Search Nested Array within Array Object for Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Consider the following array of emojis:

```
allEmojis = {
    "Smileys-People": [
        {
            "index": 1,
            "display": true,
            "name": "grinning face",
            "shortName": ":grinning:",
            "alt": "",
            "image": "_81",
            "position": "0px -80px",
            "keywords": [
                "face",
                "nice",
                "smile",
                "laugh",
                "happy",
                "smiling",
                "grin",
                "teeth",
                "cheerful",
                "cheery", 
                "grinning face"
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "display": true,
            "name": "smiling face with open mouth",
            "shortName": ":smiley:",
            "alt": "",
            "image": "_81",
            "position": "-60px -80px",
            "keywords": [
                "face",
                "open mouth",
                "awesome",
                "yay",
                "smile",
                "happy",
                "smiling",
                "grin",
                "teeth",
                "smiling face with open mouth"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Animals-Nature": [
        {
            "index": 3,
            "display": true,
            "name": "grinning face",
            "shortName": ":dog:",
            "alt": "",
            "image": "_82",
            "position": "-60px -20px",
            "keywords": [
                "animal",
                "face",
                "pet",
                "adorbs",
                "dog",
                "puppies",
                "puppy",
                "dog face"
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "display": true,
            "name": "smiling face with open mouth",
            "shortName": ":cat:",
            "alt": "",
            "image": "_82",
            "position": "-60px -80px",
            "keywords": [
                "animal",
                "face",
                "cat",
                "kitten",
                "kitty",
                "pet",
                "cat face"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have the following javascript code to search within the array and set each `display` to `true` if the `keyword` is found, set it to `false` if the `keyword` is not found. However, some keywords aren't found, even if the value of the input is the same. For example, if I search "smiling" the function works as expected, but if I search "smile" each `display` gets set to `false`.

```
emojiTitles = Object.keys(allEmojis).join(",").split(',')

const emojiSeacrh = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    
    for (let emojiTitle of emojiTitles) {
        for (let emoji of allEmojis[emojiTitle]) {
            for (let keyword of emoji.keywords) {
                if (keyword.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)) {
                    emoji.display = true
                }
                else {
                    emoji.display = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    allEmojis = allEmojis
}
```

I realize my `emojiSearch` function isn't the right way to go, but it's the closest I could get after several hours.

I've spent hours trying to find a proper solution to this on SO, but couldn't get something that fits my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code resets display at each iteration, so the final value is merely the **last** match on the array.

```
for (let keyword of emoji.keywords) {
  if (keyword.toUpperCase().startsWith(value)) {
    emoji.display = true
  } else {
    emoji.display = false
  }
}
```

You might want to replace all of it with something like

```
emoji.display = emoji.keywords.some(keyword => keyword.toUpperCase().startsWith(value));
```

[`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns true if at least one element meets the condition, false if all conditions are false.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

```js
const allEmojis = {"Smileys-People":[{"index":1,"display":true,"name":"grinning face","shortName":":grinning:","alt":"","image":"_81","position":"0px -80px","keywords":["face","nice","smile","laugh","happy","smiling","grin","teeth","cheerful","cheery","grinning face"]},{"index":2,"display":true,"name":"smiling face with open mouth","shortName":":smiley:","alt":"","image":"_81","position":"-60px -80px","keywords":["face","open mouth","awesome","yay","smile","happy","smiling","grin","teeth","smiling face with open mouth"]}],"Animals-Nature":[{"index":3,"display":true,"name":"grinning face","shortName":":dog:","alt":"","image":"_82","position":"-60px -20px","keywords":["animal","face","pet","adorbs","dog","puppies","puppy","dog face"]},{"index":4,"display":true,"name":"smiling face with open mouth","shortName":":cat:","alt":"","image":"_82","position":"-60px -80px","keywords":["animal","face","cat","kitten","kitty","pet","cat face"]}]};

const keword = 'SMILE';

Object.keys(allEmojis)
  .forEach(key => allEmojis[key] = allEmojis[key].map(obj => ({
    ...obj,
    display: obj.keywords.some(tag => tag.toUpperCase().startsWith(keword))
  })));
  
console.log(allEmojis);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```